# What's the name of the field that deals with the geometry of roots, as shown in the "Beauty of Roots" blog?

Tags: reference-request, roots

I was looking recently at John Baez' ["Beauty of Roots" blog](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/) and was completely taken away by how gorgeous the pictures were.

> What’s the actual name of the field of maths that deals with the geometry of roots?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the linked paper, it is the theory of [fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal).