# What maths do I need to study fractals in-depth?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, roots, fractals

What I’m interested in trying to understand is how roots of polynomials distribute themselves in the affine space we are working over. I’d like to understand why the roots of certain polynomials form fractal shapes, or more generally why they distribute themselves in certain geometric ways.

My question is what mathematics do I require to be able to understand the geometric properties of roots?

I’m currently studying metric spaces, real analysis and ring theory in college and am wondering what else I would need?

Comment: I think you have already asked this question. The answer is "fractals". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448339/whats-the-name-of-the-field-that-deals-with-the-geometry-of-roots-as-shown-in

Comment: Oh yea thank you, what I should’ve asked was what maths do I need to study fractals in-depth? So do I need topology, algebraic geometry or such and such?

Comment: To study fractals "in depth" you surely need at least real analysis. Whether that's enough or not depends on the depth you want and  what you hope to do with your understanding and where you are starting. If you [edit] the question to tell us that perhaps we can help.

Comment: Hope maybe my edit is more informative now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is enough to get started. You may not need to wait for more course work. Begin reading articles on the topic. When you see mathematics you don't know, look up the particulars, perhaps ask focused questions here.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I feel like complex analysis might also be important?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm not an expert either. Probably, but probably not right away.

Comment: That seems fair.